# Site not displaying properly in old versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, internet-explorer

I'm having a very hard time figuring out why my site won't display properly in old versions of IE.

You can view my demo site [here](http://testsite24.netai.net/public/demo.html)

I've attached screenshots showing how different IE versions display my site.

To put it simply, the site contains one unordered list, which contains many different list items (represented by green boxes)
There should only be 3 green boxes per row.

In IE 8, the layout is totally wrong. The green boxes aren't displayed, and there
is no structure to the page (see IE8 screenshot)

In IE9, the green boxes are displayed, but they do not line up properly (see IE9)

In IE 10, it displays fine except the green navigation bar at the top is shown as a stack, 
as opposed to a horizontal row (this occurs in IE8/IE9 too).

In IE 11, it displays totally fine.

**The individual list item code is:**

```
<li class="list__item2">
    <figure class="list__item__inner">
            <a class="divLink" href="http://www.ddd/Properties/Gammie/details.html">
    <p class="vignette" style="background-image:url(http://www.containermodularhouse.com/photo/pl728931-modern_prefab_bungalow_homes_angle_steel_frame_for_villa_and_small_house_wlh_bgl010.jpg)"></p>
    <div class="titlebox">Sample Title</div>
       <div class="locationbox">Sample Title</div>
     <div class="pricebox">Sample Title</div>
     </a>
    </li>
```

**I'm using the FlexWrap webkit to align the boxes, it's script is:**

```
<script>

;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
{
    'use strict';

    var s = document.body || document.documentElement, s = s.style;
    if( s.webkitFlexWrap == '' || s.msFlexWrap == '' || s.flexWrap == '' ) return true;

    var $list       = $( '.list' ),
        $items      = $list.find( '.list__item__inner' ),
        setHeights  = function()
        {
            $items.css( 'height', 'auto' );

            var perRow = Math.floor( $list.width() / $items.width() );
            if( perRow == null || perRow < 2 ) return true;

            for( var i = 0, j = $items.length; i < j; i += perRow )
            {
                var maxHeight   = 0,
                    $row        = $items.slice( i, i + perRow );

                $row.each( function()
                {
                    var itemHeight = parseInt( $( this ).outerHeight() );
                    if ( itemHeight > maxHeight ) maxHeight = itemHeight;
                });
                $row.css( 'height', maxHeight );
            }
        };

    setHeights();
    $( window ).on( 'resize', setHeights );
    $list.find( 'img' ).on( 'load', setHeights );

})( jQuery, window, document );

</script>
```

The entire CSS is within the html code. Viewing the page source can show you this.

How do I make my page appear in all IE versions properly (like in IE 11?)

Thank you!

**IE 8:**
[image: IE8]

**IE 9:**
[image: IE9]

**IE 10:**
[image: IE10]

**IE 11:**
[image: IE 11]

Comment: Flexbox isn't supported in IE below 10,  with only partial support in IE 10.  you can check at http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Darn, is there a work-around?

Comment: + `figure` element is not supported in IE<9.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work, without starting from scratch?

Comment: No. If you must make it work in IE8, don't use features not supported by IE8. Otherwise, just accept that it will look like crap.

Comment: Can you offer an alternative to flexbox that *will* work in IE8?

Comment: I simply need there to be 3 list items per row. If a new list item is added between #1 and #2,  the previous #2 should move into position #3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Flexie which polyfills Flexbox. It enables the 2009 Flexbox model although it currently does not have polyfill for the new specification

https://github.com/doctyper/flexie